# My computer instantly reboots without any warning

Tags: windows-10, restart

```
**EventID 41 
 
   Version 8 
 
   Level 1 
 
   Task 63 
 
   Opcode 0 
 
   Keywords 0x8000400000000002 
 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2021-09-26T18:19:37.8668359Z 
 
   EventRecordID 1614 
 
   Correlation 
 
  - Execution 
   [ ProcessID]  4 
   [ ThreadID]  8 
 
   Channel System 
 
   Computer DESKTOP-IJTG7GS 
 
  - Security 
   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 
 
- EventData 
  BugcheckCode 0 
  BugcheckParameter1 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter2 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter3 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter4 0x0 
  SleepInProgress 6 
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0 
  BootAppStatus 3221226017 
  Checkpoint 0 
  ConnectedStandbyInProgress false 
  SystemSleepTransitionsToOn 1 
  CsEntryScenarioInstanceId 0 
  BugcheckInfoFromEFI false 
  CheckpointStatus 0 
  CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2 0 
  LongPowerButtonPressDetected false**
```

So my computer restarts abruptly on it's own sometimes. I have tested ram and overheating issue but did not find any problem. I even installed windows again but the problem keeps on coming. Above is the event viewer critical error details. Please tell me what is the problem and how should i fix it. I am guessing it might be power supply. Just to be sure, what do you think it is.
My CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz it sits at 50 to 75 Celsius under load. normally its below 50. I have 20 gb ram and a 1050 ti. By the way i tested the pc after removing 1050 ti and placing quadro 4000 in it. But the problem did not solve. At one point computer would not even boot it kept on restarting at the booting screen. I don't know what to do...Help!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it can be the PSU.

Windows Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) is a known windows error screen that appears now and then, randomly when some system drivers get corrupted, incompatible apps got installed, drivers outdated, etc. One such error is BSOD 0x8000400000000002. This error is related to kernel 41 critical error on Windows 10. And this is the same error you got. You can try:

1. Update the drivers: Open windows Device manager and from there you can update your drivers.
2. Turn off Fast Startup
3. Use a Restore Point, if you have one.
4. Unistall Recent Windows Update

Click on Start and open settings.
From settings, open Windows Update & Security option.
Then select “View Update History“
From the new page, click on “Uninstall Updates“.
Now, right-click on recently installed update and select Uninstall option.
Do uninstall all recent updates one by one and then restart your PC.

5. Update your BIOS